# Window Resize with Mouse drag?

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF Application.I want to implement Resize the window(whatever size) using mouse drag with window corners or sides. like notepad or wordpad.Controls are strecthed according to window size.

can any one help on this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Window class (<Window> element) comes with style that is 'Resizeable' - that is a thik border which the user can resize by dragging. If you do nothing to the Visual Studio's generated WPF Window item you'll get a resizeable Window: The property that dictates this behavior is ResizeMode. If you want to have a little Grip, then set the followign property: ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"

There are many ways to acheive controls proportional to the embedding element. One common method is to use the  element, and define ahd columns width and row heights in terms of '*'. The example below will drow two buttons that are 2/5 of the height each:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```